# Neo4j Traversal not load all properties

Tags: properties, neo4j, traversal

During my Traversal, I look at one property.
But it seems that all properties are loaded, which makes the Traversal slower.
Is there are way to configure a lazy load for properties I don't want to look at?

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description().evaluator( Evaluators.atDepth(1) );
for ( Path p : td.traverse( myNode ) ) {
    String nodeName = (String) p.endNode().getProperty("name");
    // do some stuff
}
```

I only found a clue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/abLNOSQXfvU)...

Thanks!

===

Edit : My goal is to sort the nodes by names, for example movies...

Comment: Only the "light" properties are loaded on the first access for properties. Heavy properties like long strings or arrays are only loaded on access.

Comment: Please remember that your queries are usually executed on a hot dataset that is in cache, so then no extra loading occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon first access of any property of a node or relationship all properties are loaded into memory, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/performance-guide.html#_neo4j_primitives_lifecycle.

Best practice for high performant traversals is to change your graph model in a way that the traversal does not have to touch properties while traversing. Depending on your domain you can get to that by e.g. using more verbose relationship types or by the usage of labels in Neo4j 2.0.

You're code snippets uses the deprecated traversals, you should migrate your code to use the Traversal API as documented at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, I don't see how I could change my graph model.
My goal is to sort nodes by name.
For example, sort movies names.
In this case, the movies names should not be types or labels, am I wrong?

Comment: Don't know your use case, but if you often need movies sorted by names you might want to organize them in a linked list using `previous` and/or `next` relationships.

Comment: Finally i migrated to 2.0 to enjoy labels.
It doesn't fit my model 100% but it helps. Thanks!